# How to execute MySQL 'CREATE VIEW' in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: zend-db

I tried following, is it the way to do?

```
$sql_group = $db->query("CREATE VIEW `branchfromgroup` AS (SELECT `tbl_group`.`Sno` FROM `tbl_group` LEFT JOIN `tbl_branch` ON `tbl_group`.`branchId` = `tbl_branch`.`Sno` WHERE (`tbl_branch`.`Sno` = '4'))");
```